# Javascript Algorithm to use for applying multiple discounts in a promotional sales event

Tags: javascript, algorithm, calculation, discount

We have a promo sales event on our store which is if you buy 1 Keyboard, you Get 20% off, if you Buy 2 Keyboards, Get 30% off, Buy 3 Keyboards, Get 40% off. Given the Keyboard's product price is USD 199.99. There is a maximum limit of only 6 keyboards where you can apply discount, if you buy more than that, no more additional discounts will be applied.

Can anyone help me to create an algorithm to apply the discount and to compute the total amount if customer buys 1 up to 6 or more of this specific product?

```
Buy 1 Keyboard  = 20% discount
Buy 2 Keyboards = 30% discount
Buy 3 Keyboards = 40% discount
```

This was the first code I tried to solve the our issue but I was getting incorrect results:

```
let cart = [];
let disc_amount;
let total_amount;

discFor1 = 0.2;
discFor2 = 0.3;
discFor3 = 0.4;
discFor4 = 0.6;
discFor5 = 0.7;
discFor6 = 0.8;

const keyboard = {
    id: "1001",
    name: "Yamaha PSR-E273 Keyboard",
    reg_price: 199.99,
    disc_price: 0
};


const addKeyboardToCart = () => {
    cart.push(keyboard);
};

const getDiscount = (cart) => {
    if (cart.length < 1) {
        console.log("Please add an item");
    }

    if (cart.length === 1) {
        disc_amount = keyboard.reg_price * discFor1;
    } else if (cart.length === 2) {
        disc_amount = keyboard.reg_price * discFor2;
    } else if (cart.length === 3) {
        disc_amount = keyboard.reg_price * discFor3;
    } else if (cart.length === 4) {
        disc_amount = keyboard.reg_price * discFor4;
    } else if (cart.length === 5) {
        disc_amount = keyboard.reg_price * discFor5;
    } else if (cart.length === 6) {
        disc_amount = keyboard.reg_price * discFor6;
    } else if (cart.length > 6) {
        disc_amount = keyboard.reg_price * discFor6;
    }

    return disc_amount;
};

const getTotalAmount = (disc_amount, cart) => {
    let total_reg_price_amount = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        total_reg_price_amount += cart[i].reg_price;
    }
    total_amount = total_reg_price_amount - disc_amount;

    return total_amount;
};

addKeyboardToCart();
addKeyboardToCart();
addKeyboardToCart();
addKeyboardToCart();
addKeyboardToCart();
addKeyboardToCart();

getDiscount(cart);

getTotalAmount(disc_amount, cart);
```

Edit: I'm also trying to implement how to get the best discount for the customer that's why I'm trying to apply the discount dynamically instead of hard-coding the discount amount for every number of items ordered.

Edit:
I revised my question and removed additional questions so that the answers can focus more on a specific problem.

Comment: Please simplify the logic and code example to a minimum to make it easy for others to help to solve the problem. Actually you could use the products length in cart to calculate the discount. ;o)

Comment: Ok i will try that now thanks for the tip

Comment: @monkey-0001 I tried to simplify my approach but another problem is I can't seem to make it so that the discount is applied correctly when getting more than 6 items.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified the problem a little bit but kept the same logic that you were following:

I also added small test function to test out the function for all the cases you want. I already added some. You can add more if you want.

Edited to Add : How to calculate totalPrice and also add more testcases

```
keyboard = {
  reg_price: 200
}
const discFor1 = 0.20
const discFor2 = 0.30
const discFor3 = 0.40
const getDiscount = (cart_length) => {
  switch ( cart_length ) {
    case 1 : return keyboard.reg_price * discFor1;
    case 2 : return keyboard.reg_price * 2 * discFor2;
    case 3 : return keyboard.reg_price * 3 * discFor3;
    case 4 : return keyboard.reg_price * 3 * discFor3 + keyboard.reg_price * discFor1;
    case 5 : return keyboard.reg_price * 3 * discFor3 + keyboard.reg_price * 2 * discFor2;
    default : return keyboard.reg_price * 6 * discFor3;
  }
};

const getTotalAmount = (cart) => {
  if (cart.length == 0) {
    console.log("Please add an item")
    return;
  }
    total_amount = cart.length * keyboard.reg_price - getDiscount(cart.length);
    return total_amount;
};

const test = ( cart, ans ) => {
  if ( getTotalAmount(cart) !== ans) {
    console.log(`Error: expected ${ans}, received ${getTotalAmount(cart)}`)
  } else {
    console.log(`Success: expected ${ans}, received ${getTotalAmount(cart)}`)
  }
}

test([], undefined)
test(["keybd"], 200 - 40)
test(["keybd", "keybd"], 400 - 120)
test(["keybd", "keybd", "keybd"], 600 - 240)
test(["keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd"], 800 - 280)
test(["keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd"], 1000 - 360)
test(["keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd"], 1200 - 480)
test(["keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd"], 1400 - 480)
test(["keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd", "keybd"], 1600 - 480)
```

Comment: thanks for your response! Is there a way to consider a dynamic addition of discounts? What I mean is because there might be other combinations for discount total like for example if the customer bought 6 items, then we have two different options: discFor3 x 2 or discFor2 x 3, but discFor3 x 2 is lesser than discFor2 x 3. Is there a way to get the best discount dynamically or we really have to hardcode it?

Comment: @SpringBlanket : For your problem set , there will only be one best answer so you can actually hardcode it but yes, if you want to calculate the best discount for generic cases then you will need to dynamically code it. Let me think about how to do it. By the way, in your example 
`keyboard_price * 6 * 0.4`
is more than `keyboard_price * 6 * 0.3 ` so my solution is actually correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, this solution solves this problem, thanks!